# How come the regular URL won't work with facebook apps?

Tags: html, facebook, url

In my app I have a logo and when it's clicked I need it to direct the user back to a page on facebook.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/company.com" id="logo" target="_self"><img src="images/company_logo.png"></a>
```

but this just gives the user a white screen.

So why doesn't the regular URL work and how does it need to like in order to get it working?

Comment: Is this link placed within an iframe application on Facebook?

Comment: Yes, it's within an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your application is sitting in an iframe, you'll want to **redirect the top most frame** to the URL. Your current method would only perform the redirect *within the iframe*. To redirect the top most frame you'll have to change your `target` attribute to `_top`:

```
<a href="SOME_URL" id="logo" target="_top">...</a>
```

Comment: Yeah, it did but I got to wait awhile before I can accept your answer.